Use Jedis `echo` in pipeline
The examples use Scala code, but the issue would be the same with Java.
Way back in version 2 of Jedis, you could use echo in a pipeline:
import redis.clients.jedis._

object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val jedis = new Jedis("redis://localhost:6379/0")
    val pipe = jedis.pipelined()
    pipe.echo("Hello, Redis!")
    val response = pipe.syncAndReturnAll()
    println(response.get(0))
  }
}

But echo has been removed from pipelines.
The only replacement seems to be pipe.sendCommand(Protocol.Command.ECHO, "Hello, Redis!"), but this will give you back an array of bytes, not a string.
Is there still an easy way to use echo so that it immediately returns a string and we don't have to do a conversion afterwards?

You can try the following:
pipe.executeCommand(new CommandObject(new CommandArguments(Protocol.Command.ECHO).add("Hello, Redis!"), BuilderFactory.STRING))

You can also ask to add it back, preferably with the explanation of your use case.

works, but with pipe.executeCommand

@Amaterasu thanks for figuring it out. updated answer.
